# Make Riley Riddles, Not War

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

```
When a famous man sets out
With a frightening weapon in hand
In between remain I, devout
Against killing making my stand
```

What am I?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When a famous man sets out

> **Pac**-man has been amazingly entertaining since the 80s

With a frightening weapon in hand

> **fist** - a hand forming a weapon

In between remain I, devout

> **I** is infixed and with **fi** for faithful

Against killing making my stand

> a **pacifist** is against killing.

Comment: Just so. [Once again](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/67536/36023), you're about 120% correct: I tried to extend the straight clue to the surface reading of the wordplay clues, (which is why I had to get rid of all the "fixes"), so the "devout" was supposed to be more of a straight clue with a nod towards the [tag:rhyme] tag than an actual wordplay clue. Clearly I need to be more careful about adding unintended cleverness in the future. :-)